# Detect if Google Satellite Images Available

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps API is it possible to detect whether or not satellite tiles will be available given coordinates and a zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Read the "Maximum Zoom Imagery" section of the Google Maps API v3 for an explanation and a code sample.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#MaxZoom

Here is the sample code from that documentation that "shows a map of metropolitan Tokyo. Clicking anywhere on the map indicates the maximum zoom level at that location. (Zoom levels around Tokyo generally vary between zoom levels 18 and 21.)"

```js
var map;
var maxZoomService = new google.maps.MaxZoomService();

var tokyo = new google.maps.LatLng(35.6894875, 139.6917064);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: tokyo,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', showMaxZoom);
}

function showMaxZoom(e) {
  maxZoomService.getMaxZoomAtLatLng(e.latLng, function(response) {
    if (response.status != google.maps.MaxZoomStatus.OK) {
      alert("Error in MaxZoomService");
      return;
    } else {
      alert("The maximum zoom at this location is: " + response.zoom);
    }
    map.setCenter(e.latLng);
  });
}
```

Comment: That answer does not help international readers because Google delivers translated documentation which misses your code example (at least the German version).

Comment: @Bananeweizen: Not sure if it will help at all, but I edited the answer to include the relevant sample code.  (I'm very surprised that the German language documentation is incomplete.)

Comment: For example in Brazil the max zoom at country side is 19 the big cities the max zoom is 20 ..

Comment: @Fernando:  Right!  Detecting the maximum zoom level is what the code does.  (The code above is written for Tokyo, Japan.)  I see that Google's Brazilian Portugese translation also does not have this sample code.  Again, surprising and a shame.  Hopefully it will be updated very soon.